# drawbacks of using new/delete in ANSI C

Tags: c++, memory-management

if I wrote an ANSI C code, and I used new and delete operators for dynamic memory management.
Are there any drawbacks for using it?

```
extern "C" void allocateString(char **str, int size) {
   *str = new char[size];
}
```

It is just a sample code.

Comment: Most important drawback is that `new` **is not in C**.

Comment: What is new in C :-)

Comment: @Klaus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99 :-)

Comment: This is a C++ function, exported with "C" external linkage - not ANSI C code. The drawback is that you will have to deallocate str in the calling code (or have a memory leak) and unless you provide a corresponding `deallocateString` API, client code will have to guess that it should use `delete[] *str` to do so correctly. This is poor C++ API design.

Comment: Removed C and ANSI tags from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `new` or `delete` form part of ANSI C. They are part of the C++ standard.

In C dynamic memory allocation on the heap is performed using `malloc()`, `free()` and associated *functions* which form part of the C library (rather than being native to the language itself as the `new` and `delete` *operators* are in C++).

Using them thus relies on your C compiler not confirming the C standard (or more accurately supporting an extension to it which is not part of the standard).

Better to pick one language or the other, and avoid a mish-mash of both.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not include the new and delete operators.